# Windows XP или Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows

Что лучше для рабочей станции?

Answer (score 2):

windows xp  если она версии PRO можно ввести в домен  в качестве рабочей станции.А вот win serv2003 это полноценные сервер - можно конечно его использовать для работы пользователя только зачем? платить за более дорогую лицензию и т.д.

Comment: 1. Платить не надо, в России софт бесплатен :)2. Бытует в народе мнение, что серверная ось более производительная, более надёжная, более гибкая в том числе как и рабочая станция! Вот и хотел узнать у тех кто сам производил сравнения для использования в качестве рабочей станции (не игровой)

Comment: 1. тоже вариант :)2. как вариант поставить windows xp corporate редакцию.Делать из 2003 сервера рабочии станции конечно можно, но это не по феншую.К железу 2003 сервер менее требователен, но на него уже никогда не будут приходить обновления, а вот xp ещё полтора года будет обновляться...

Comment: Собственно, я работал на W2K3 в режиме станции и, достаточно много - на XP. Так что исходя из личного опыта скажу, что комфортнее работать на сервере. Однако встречалась пара (действительно редких) приложений. которые ввиду несовместимости с серверной осью не могли работать (специально встроенные программные ограничения) - пришлось использовать XP. В остальном вполне хватает. Переустанавливать пришлось только 1 раз за несколько лет - сдох накопитель HDD. В текущих реалиях я соглашусь, что богатство функционала этой ОСи не нужно обычному пользователю - Windows 7 выигрывает в этом плане.

Answer (score 1):

Товарищ, если ставить ws2003, то по умолчанию там запущены лишние сервисы (перечислять не буду сами можете посмотреть). А вот чистая winXP, доведенная до нормального состояния с обновками, даст Вам и офисному планктону уверенность в работе.

Answer (score 0):

для рабочей станции следует использовать то, что для нее предназначено по функционалу.В любой серверной версии полно всяческих сервисов/демонов, которые обычному офисному работнику ну совершенно не нужны, и при этом будут занимать память.Коль у вас все под виндой, то ставим ХРюшуPRO или W7Unlim/Corporate.Даже в 32-х битной вариации. Не знаю пока, за редким исключением, зачем офисному сотруднику, с его Вордом и Экселем более 1га оперативы...

Answer (score -1):

> win serv2003 это полноценные сервер

Это только одно название, а не сервер. Windows-это пользовательская ОС.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы не приведете ни одного аргумента в защиту своей теории.

Comment: А нужно? Практика ничего не показует вам?

Comment: Как раз таки практика показывает, что такие заявления беспочвенны. Ибо:1. Если сделать все верно, стабильности серверу не занимать2. Представление о сервере у всех разные. Если сервер для вас - это побольше сервисов, аля ftp, http... это одно. Но если у вас несколько лесов и доменов с `N` виндовых компьютеров, это совершенно другой разговор3. Я более чем уверен, что вы и близко не видели функциональность Windows, без использования графической оболочки, которая, кстати не редко косячит4. У всего есть свои цели и задачи, а беспочвенные заявления ведут к холивару

Comment: Прямо отвечая на ваш вопрос, моя практика показывает, что с минимумом требуемых телодвижений вы "поднимаете" то, что вам необходимо, подтачиваете утилитами до нужной кондиции, так как очень уж много всяких настроек хранит реестр и сервер готов. Все из коробки: домен, пользователи, компьютеры, их настройки, сертификация, виртуализация и еще много чего. Ответы по настройке лежат в одном месте, всегда доступны и просты.Пользовательская ОС - MAC OS X. Даже несмотря на Unix в ядре, для содержания парка машин функционала маловато да и стабильности не хватает.

Comment: "Если сделать все верно, стабильности серверу не занимать"Только не нужно говорить за стабильность ещё у Windows её нет. Сколько раз она у вас перезагружается в неделю?"Но если у вас несколько лесов и доменов с N виндовых компьютеров,"Не будет у меня никаких Windows компьютеров.И ещё, что там с безопасностью в Windows? Её там нет просто.

Comment: После последних критических обновлений аптайм был 27 дней:). У пользователей от суток до нескольких дней. Тестовые машинки вообще не выключаются. На ноутбуках у работников хибернейт месяцами работает.Повторюсь, нужно уметь работать с тем, что наиболее выгодно и предпочтительно в определенной ситуации. У всех ОС есть недостатки и достоинства. И, естественно, что у Windows, имеющей, несмотря на ваши высказывания, огромнейшую аудиторию, недостатков масса. Но ее знают люди, человек пришел на работу, работать, а не разбираться в тонкостях новой ОС.

Comment: В-общем, аргументы данного ответа сводятся к одной фразе: "Патамушта!"  Это не правильно.